How much coal is needed to generate electricity for 1 person?
In one month a person uses $852$ kWh of electricity. Using a fossil-fueled vapor power plant, find how much coal is needed for one person.
The assumptions are:
Boiler efficiency of the Rankine cycle is $80$%
Efficiency of the electrical generator is $80$%
Coal burns completely with air and all incoming and outgoing streams are $300$K, $2$atm in the boiler
Ideal Rankine cycle with steam as working fluid
Sat. vapor enters turbine at $8$MPa and sat. liquid exits the condenser at $0.008$MPa
First, I found the total how much kW the generator would need to generate at any given moment
$$852 \frac{kWh}{month}*\frac{1 month}{30 days}*\frac{1day}{24hours}=1.183kW$$
Then applying the effiency of the generator I get $1.47875$kW that needs to be the net output of the system.
Going through the system analysis with steam tables I found that $h_1=2758 \frac{kJ}{kg}$,$h_2=1794.77\frac{kJ}{kg}$,$h_3=173.88\frac{kJ}{kg}$,$h_4=181.94 \frac{kJ}{kg}$ $$\frac{\dot{W}_t}{\dot{m}}=963.23\frac{kJ}{kg}$$
$$\frac{\dot{W}_p}{\dot{m}}=8.06\frac{kJ}{kg}$$
Knowing that the $\dot{W}_{cycle}= 1.47875$kW I can find the mass flow rate
$$\dot{m}=\frac{1.47875}{963.23-8.06}=0.00155\frac{kg}{s}$$
Now I analyzed the combustion reaction to be
$$C+O_2\rightarrow CO_2$$
where 1 kmole of oxygen is needed to burn 1 kmole of carbon, then applying this to the energy balance equation I get
$$(\bar{h}^o_f+\Delta\bar{h})_{CO_2}-(\bar{h}^o_f+\Delta\bar{h})_{C}-(\bar{h}^o_f+\Delta\bar{h})_{O_2}=\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{n}_C}$$
the enthalpy of formation of both $O_2$ and carbon is zero and the $\Delta \bar{h}$ of carbon is also zero. Then plugging in for the values at $300$K
$$(-393520+(9431-9364))-(8736-8682)=\dot{Q}$$
$$\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{n}_C}=-393507\frac{kJ}{kmol}$$
Now to change the $kmol$ to $kg$ I multiplied by the molecular weight of carbon
$$\dot{Q}=-4726019.07\frac{kJ}{kg}$$
Now applying the boiler effiency which I believe to mean that $80$% of the heat added from combustion is transfered into the working fluid.
$$0.8\frac{\dot{Q}_{in}}{\dot{m}_C}=\frac{\dot{Q}_{out}}{\dot{m}_{water}}$$
And from the Rankine cycle analyse, we can find the heat added from the boiler which in the equation above is labeled as $\dot{Q}_{out}$
$$\dot{Q}_{in}=\dot{m}(h_1-h_4)$$
So rearranging for $\dot{m}_C$ we get
$$\dot{m}_C=\frac{\dot{m}(h_1-h_4)}{(\dot{m}_{water})(.8\dot{Q}_{in})}$$
So is my work correct or have I made so error in my math and/or assumptions?

That looks complicated.
I keep a few numbers in my head for "that sounds about right" calculations. For oil I use 10 kWh/kg. Coal is about 2/3 of that, so 6.7 kWh/kg. For coal steam plant efficiency, without looking it up, I would expect 35% to 40%. So ...
$$ Coal\ required = \frac {Energy} {Energy\ density \times efficiency} = \frac {852} { 6.6 \times 0.4} = 322\ \text{kg} $$
Coal Education states that it takes 1 lb (0.45 kg) of coal per kWh and 852 × 0.45 = 383 kg. (The two calculations differ by 20% which isn't bad for unknown grades of coal and plant efficiencies.)
I don't know if that helps you at all, but it's a lot easier.

Superb analysis and explained to allow more detail to be included as OP wants.
